# Excel - Find and replace those comma not within parenthesis

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have rows on my excel that has following values below.

```
Brandon (39042, 39047),Pearl (39208),Fondren and Belhaven,North Jackson (39206,39211),Byram (39272),South Jackson (39212, (39204),Clinton (39056),Madison (39110),Ridgeland (39157),West Jackson (39209)
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is change the comma that separate each values into semi-colon, wherein those comma within parentheses ie. (39042, 39047) shouldn't be affected.

Already tried googling but cannot find anything.

Comment: perform a search and replace on ")," and replace with ");".  It really looks like you are trying to delete the coma that follows the ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in A1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, ")," , ");" )
```

I put spaces in for easier reading.  Copy the formula down as far as you can go.

Alternatively use the built in search and replace function of excel. <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

[image: pic]